# May I have bold mathfraktur?

Tags: symbols, bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

I want a bold version of `$\mathfrak{H}$`. How may I have one?

Comment: `unicode-math` has it. For pdflatex probably not.

Comment: @Symbol1 see campa's answer...

Comment: TIL. Either I have never seen bold frak before or I did but cannot tell the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For reference, the `unicode-math` command for bold Fraktur is `\symbffrak{a}`.

[image: bold Fraktur]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\Large
$
\symnormal{a} +
\symliteral{a}+
\symbb{a} +
\symbbit{a}+ 
\symcal{a} +
\symscr{a} +
\symfrak{a}+ 
\symsfup{a} +
\symsfit{a} +
\symbfsf{a} +
\symbfup{a} +
\symbfit{a} +
\symbfcal{a}+
\symbfscr{a}+
\fbox{$\symbffrak{a}$}+
\symbfsfup{a}+
\symbfsfit{a} 
$

$
\mathnormal{cos}\theta+
 \mathbb{cos}\theta+
 \mathbbit{cos}\theta+
 \mathcal{cos}\theta+
 \mathscr{cos}\theta+
 \mathfrak{cos}\theta+
 \mathsfup{cos}\theta+
 \mathsfit{cos}\theta+
\mathbfsf{cos}\theta+
 \mathbfup{cos}\theta+
 \mathbfit{cos}\theta+
 \mathbfcal{cos}\theta+
\mathbfscr{cos}\theta+
 \mathbffrak{cos}\theta+
 \mathbfsfup{cos}\theta+
 \mathbfsfit{cos}\theta+
 $

$
\symnormal{π} *
\symliteral{π}*
\symbb{π} *
%\symbbit{π}* 
%\symcal{π} *
%\symscr{π} *
%\symfrak{π}* 
%\symsfup{π} *
%\symsfit{π} *
\symbfsf{π} *
\symbfup{π} *
\symbfit{π} *
%\symbfcal{π}*
%\symbfscr{π}*
%\fbox{$\symbffrak{π}$}*
%\symbfsfup{π}*
\symbfsfit{π} 
$ 
\end{document}
```